# Enabling IIS Failed Request Tracing at the root (not a particular site)

Tags: iis, rewrite, iis-8.5

I have some URL Rewrite rules at the root of IIS (i.e. not in a specific site).  They are at the root because they Route to Server Farm, and apparently that has to be done at the root (I don't see the option for "Route to a Server Farm" when I create a URL Rewrite rule on a site.)

I would like to enable Failed Request Tracing so I can see what's going on with this particular rule, but I don't see a way to enable it at the root, only on a site-by site basis.  How do I enable Failed Request Tracing at the root?

Answer (score 1):

Add the Failed Request Tracing rule to the web site for which its bindings match the URL being used. The explanation for this is that ARR is still running on a worker process. The only purpose of global URL Rewrite rules is to make them global to all web sites.